# Flutter IOS & ANDROID Widgets Implementation

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I wanted to ask about the implementation of **IOS & Android Widgets** for Flutter.

**Current Scenario :**
Basically, i have developed the app on android platform and now i want to **convert it to IOS platform**. Since this is my first app, i really need some experienced voice on some issues i am facing.

**Questions :**

**1 -** Is there any simple way to **detect that the widgets currently used are of Android/IOS** Platform ?
How can we know for sure that a specific widget is of Android platform and is not going to work on IOS platform and vice versa.

**2 -** If somehow we know for sure that the current widget we are using is of Android platform, then how can we find its **equivalent widget to implement for IOS platform**.

**3 -** Are these widgets specifically required when we are going to **upload/publish** to these platforms respective stores. For example in a scenario where i hadn't converted all of my android app widgets to ios widgets and when i try to publish the app for IOS store, does the **IOS Store** rejects that or not?

Any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

All standard widgets will work on iOS as is. Flutter paints the UI, rather than call the native APIs. You might use a plugin that does not support iOS, but I have not yet come across such a plugin on pub.dev.

If you want to write platform specific code, you can import `dart:io` and use the boolean `Platform.isIOS` or `Platform.isAndroid`.

Both the App Store and Play Store have specific requirements before your app is approved.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Mostly all packages on pub.dev have a specific set of rules for both platforms. My major concern was of the layout/widgets used for both platforms to make same sense of difference between these platforms.

Comment: You can always run the code on a iOS Simulator.

Comment: Will do. It is still unclear for me to see some equivalent widgets for both platforms. Anyhow, thanks for the help. Will post some information after getting things done.

Comment: Some Material widgets are adaptive; for example you can use `Switch.adaptive()` to change appearance based on platform. You can also use the [Cupertino library](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/cupertino-library.html)

Answer (score 0):

In case you really want to have Android specific widgets on Android devices and iOS specific widgets on iOS devices, then use the [Flutter Platform Widgets](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_platform_widgets) package. This will exactly do that - drawing iOS buttons using the Cupertino library and Android buttons using the Android library (and most other widgets as well).

As @Mudassir mentioned in the other comment this is not a requirement. In case you go with the default widgets, you will have the same look on all devices (even web, Windows, etc.).